# Identifying a transformer

Tags: transformer

I bought an electroplasma lamp from Lave the original, and the lamp is basically a plasma globe.  I took out the circuit within the lamp, and it had a transformer with a sticker FB-DY-200B CB, is that the identification of the transformer because I have searched  FB-DY-200B CB, and I can not find a datasheet for the transformer? I need to identify the pins of the transformer since it has 5 pins, and wire sticking out making it 6 I guess, making it I believe a transformer that has two primary coils, and 1 secondary coil.  The transformer has a thin copper winding which was connected to two pins before I desoldered in order to understand the transformer, but I was still puzzled, on how to identify the pins.  Is there a method to identify the pins of the transformer?

Comment: Hi, Jose. (1) A picture is worth 1000 words. (2) You're supposed to ask a question.

Comment: Voting to close because the intent of the posting is not at all clear. If it about repair the the question would be closed anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite likely the number on your transformer is a number for a custom OEM part and there is no information published.

The "flying lead" is likely the high-voltage output node.  It comes out separately to maintain safe spacing to keep the high voltage from arcing uselessly.

You could work out how the transformer is wired by taking careful resistance measurements from each pair of transformer pins.  And then by reverse-engineering the circuit around the transformer.

If there is active circuitry (transistors, integrated circuits, etc.) inside, then it seems possible the transformer is driven from a high-frequency oscillator. and one of the windings may be some sort of feedback for the oscillator.

Answer (score 0):

In order to more fully understand the transformer, you should measure the diameter of the wires comprising the windings, count the number of turns in each, and then characterize the core.